# Adding Random Element to GenericList in C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, arraylist, data-structures, generic-list

I am trying to make a simple food delivery system by using data structures. I hold the Neighborhood names in an ArrayList and I hold the Delivery Count, Food Name and it's count in GenericList. I drew the schematic and attached the photo.

[image: The Schematic (Composite Data Structure)]

I coded the program which prints the "Hood Name and it's delivery count" my code and my outputs are here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace temp

{
    
    internal class delivery
    {
        public string food;
        public int count;

    }
    internal class Hood
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Number;
    }
    class programm
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        
        {

            string[] HoodName = { "Cherryhood", "NewCastle", "Greenlight", "Summerlin", "Westcity", "Paradise", "Legions", "Flamingos" };
            int[] TeslimatSayisi = { 4, 2, 7, 2, 7, 3, 0, 1 };
            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
            int counter = 0;
            List<Hood> genericList;
            Hood ClassExample;

            for (int i = 0; i < HoodName.Length;)
            {
                genericList = new List<Hood>();
                int elementCount = (int)Math.Pow(2, counter);
                for (int j = 0; j < elementCount; j++)
                {
                    ClassExample = new Hood();
                    ClassExample.Name = HoodName[i];
                    ClassExample.Number = TeslimatSayisi[i];
                    genericList.Add(ClassExample);
                    i++;
                    if (i == HoodName.Length) break;
                }
                arrayList.Add(genericList);
                counter++;
            }
            int counter2 = 0;
            foreach (List<Hood> temp in arrayList)
            {
                foreach (Hood temp2 in temp)
                    Console.WriteLine("Hood: " + temp2.Name +" | "+" Delivery Count: " + temp2.Number);
            }
```

My outputs are:

```
Hood: Cherryhood |  Delivery Count: 4
Hood: NewCastle |  Delivery Count: 2
Hood: Greenlight |  Delivery Count: 7
Hood: Summerlin |  Delivery Count: 2
Hood: Westcity |  Delivery Count: 7
Hood: Paradise |  Delivery Count: 3
Hood: Legions |  Delivery Count: 0
Hood: Flamingos |  Delivery Count: 1
```

How can I get an output like this:

```
Hood: Cherryhood |  Delivery Count: 4 | Food's, count: Salat:2, Taco:5, Pizza:1, Burger:2
Hood: NewCastle |  Delivery Count: 2 | Food's, count: Pasta:15, Cake,7 
Hood: Greenlight |  Delivery Count: 7 | Food's, count: ................
Hood: Summerlin |  Delivery Count: 2 | ..........
Hood: Westcity |  Delivery Count: 7 |...........
Hood: Paradise |  Delivery Count: 3 |.................
Hood: Legions |  Delivery Count: 0 |...........
Hood: Flamingos |  Delivery Count: 1 |.....................
```

I can guess I have to make a food list and count list like this:

```
foods = {pizza, taco, burger, salad, pasta, cake..........}
count = {1, 5, 2, 2, 15 ,7...........}
```

I need to create the delivery class (containing the Meal Name, Quantity fields). Then I have to fill each of the Generic Lists in the ArrayList with the number of Delivery objects in the relevant neighborhood. I can create a food list and randomly select food information from there. For this project, We can assume that each delivery can consist of only one type of meal (including how many).

I am pretty new on C# and Data Structures thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `List`s of objects to define your data structure. And then LINQ to query, manipulate, etc. I think it will be more flexible and give you closer to what you want. Something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var status = new List<Neighbourhood>{
            new Neighbourhood{
                Name = "Cherryhood",
                Id = 1,
                Orders = new List<Order>{
                    new Order{
                        Id = 300,
                        OrderItems = new List<string>{
                            "Salad",
                            "Taco",
                            "Pizza"
                        }
                    },
                    new Order{
                        Id = 301,
                        OrderItems = new List<string>{
                            "Cake",
                            "Taco",
                            "Pasta",
                            "Burger"
                        }
                    },
                    new Order{
                        Id = 302,
                        OrderItems = new List<string>{
                            "Salad",
                            "Pasta"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            new Neighbourhood{
                Name = "Newcastle",
                Id = 2,
                Orders = new List<Order>{
                    new Order{
                        Id = 400,
                        OrderItems = new List<string>{
                            "Salad",
                            "Taco",
                            "Pizza"
                        }
                    },
                    new Order{
                        Id = 401,
                        OrderItems = new List<string>{
                            "Cake",
                            "Taco",
                            "Pasta"
                        }
                    },
                    new Order{
                        Id = 402,
                        OrderItems = new List<string>{
                            "Salad",
                            "Pasta"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        Console.WriteLine($"Neighbourhoods: {status.Count}");
        foreach(var neighbourhood in status){
            Console.WriteLine($"Neighbourhood: {neighbourhood.Name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Total Orders: {neighbourhood.Orders.Count}");

            var allOrderItems = neighbourhood.Orders.SelectMany(i => i.OrderItems).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine($"Total Ordered Items: {allOrderItems.Count}");
            
            var groupedOrderItems = allOrderItems
                .GroupBy(i=>i)
                .Select(i => new {
                        Name = i.Key,
                        Total = i.Count()
                    })
                .OrderBy(i => i.Name)
                .ToList();
            
            foreach(var groupedOrderItem in groupedOrderItems){
                Console.WriteLine($"Order Item: {groupedOrderItem.Name} ({groupedOrderItem.Total})");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Neighbourhood{
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public List<Order> Orders;

        public Neighbourhood(){
            Orders = new List<Order>();
        }
    }

public class Order{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<string> OrderItems {get;set;}
    
    public Order(){
        OrderItems = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kN103N

Output:

```
Neighbourhoods: 2
Neighbourhood: Cherryhood
Total Orders: 3
Total Ordered Items: 9
Order Item: Burger (1)
Order Item: Cake (1)
Order Item: Pasta (2)
Order Item: Pizza (1)
Order Item: Salad (2)
Order Item: Taco (2)
Neighbourhood: Newcastle
Total Orders: 3
Total Ordered Items: 8
Order Item: Cake (1)
Order Item: Pasta (2)
Order Item: Pizza (1)
Order Item: Salad (2)
Order Item: Taco (2)
```

Comment: I have to have  string[] HoodName = { "Cherryhood", "NewCastle", "Greenlight", "Summerlin", "Westcity", "Paradise", "Legions", "Flamingos" };
            int[] TeslimatSayisi = { 4, 2, 7, 2, 7, 3, 0, 1 };

Comment: TeslimatSayisi means Delivery count for each neighborhood.

Comment: I don't think you should store delivery count in an array like that. I assume you want to be able to add and remove deliveries. If you store the count in an array, you will always have to go back in and update the array. It would make more sense to structure your data like I did above so that you can query the count at any time and get the current numbers.

Comment: As for 'I have to have `string[]`': if you really need that, you can still do it. I just provided some sample code to build up dummy data. Look more closely at the classes that I provided, and the LINQ queries / way that I pull out `Count` for elements

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed was that the hood class had not a list of deliveries so I added one. Secondly I extracted the methods from the main method with their responsibility. And that was the result:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        initDictionary();
        printOutDeliveries();
    }

     static void printOutDeliveries()
    {
        foreach (var hood in hoods)
        {
            string foodNumbers="";
            foreach (var del in hood.Value.Deliveries)
            {
               foodNumbers += del.food + ": " + del.count + ", ";
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Hood: " + hood.Key + " | Deliver Count: " + hood.Value.Number + " Foods count: "+foodNumbers);

        }
    }

     static Dictionary<string, Hood> hoods = new Dictionary<string, Hood>();

     static void initDictionary()
    {
        string[] HoodName = { "Cherryhood", "NewCastle", "Greenlight", "Summerlin", "Westcity", "Paradise", "Legions", "Flamingos" };
        int[] TeslimatSayisi = { 4, 2, 7, 2, 7, 3, 0, 1 };
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var name in HoodName)
        {
            hoods.Add(name, new Hood()
            {
                Name = name,
                Number = TeslimatSayisi[i++],
                Deliveries = GetRandomDeliveries()
            });
        }
    }

    static List<delivery> GetRandomDeliveries()
    {
        List<string> foods = new List<string> { "Salat", "Taco", "Pizza", "Burger", "Pasta", "Cake" };
        List<delivery> deliveries = new List<delivery>();
        var randMaxVal = foods.Count - 1;
        var random = new Random();
        var forlooplength = random.Next(randMaxVal);
        for (int i = 0; i < forlooplength; i++)
        {
            var rand = random.Next(randMaxVal);
            deliveries.Add(new delivery()
            {
                food = foods[rand]
            });
            foods.RemoveAt(rand);
        }
        return deliveries;
    }

internal class delivery
{
    public string food;
    public int count => new Random().Next(10);
}
internal class Hood
{
    public string Name;
    public int Number;
    public List<delivery> Deliveries;
}
```

Comment: Yo bro thanks for the help. I tried the run the code on my compiler but I got a lot of errors . I fixed the errors as suggested by the compiler, but when I run the code, I get no output.